# Why to do when npm live-server command (^C) is not working on Git Bash?

Tags: npm, windows-10, command, git-bash

In Windows 10 `npm live-server` command `^C` is not working on git bash:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

See if using [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) (whic comes with git bash) helps:

```
winpty liveserver
```

That will launch your server, but will also listen for SIGTERM signals (like CTRL+C)